# Is there a hotkey to subdivide geometry?

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry

I’ve been following this tutorial for a model, and I’m wondering if there’s any hotkey to change an extruded plane (like it was done in the video) from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

If not, do I need to use a cube mesh and edit it?

Comment: hit w then s whiich will subdivide the plane

Comment: @mathmaniage That sounds like an answer, care to write one?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for subdivide. It doesn't have a shortcut by default, but you can assign a custom hotkey by rightclicking on the menu item under mesh-> edges -> subdivide 
[image: This shows the path to subdivide]

in my case it's set to alt + w
[image: You can now press alt + w to subdivide]

Comment: The W shortcut works only for versions previous to 2.8

Answer (score 6):

**For Version 2.9**

In edit mode, right-click, then <kbd>S</kbd> is a quick way to do it using only the default key bindings.

Additionally, it also appears to be the first entry in the list (screen space permitting) and you can just do right-click then left-click.

Answer (score 2):

To subdivide simple go to edit mode and hit W and then S. 
To subdivide like the catmull clark go to edit mode and hit W then U after you select the required mesh geometry.

Comment: The W shortcut works only for versions previous to 2.8

Answer (score 1):

Just found out, there is a better way. In edit mode, right-click, then again right-click on "Subdivide" menu entry. Now you can assign whatever hotkey you like. Obviously this works with other menu entries as well. You just have to be lucky to find a key which is not already occupied by Blender. ;-)